# meaning of "inscription"

Tags: meaning

Does the word "inscription" ever mean "establishment" or something along those lines? I'm having difficulty understanding the following sentence, if "inscription" is to be taken literally:

> The play's (Oedipus at Colonus) explicit inscription of hero cult is one of the ways in which the gap between the worlds of the play and the audience may be bridged.

Let me add, that there is no mention of a proper inscription anywhere in the text.

Many thanks.
K.

Comment: It is strange.  But I'm guessing the intended meaning is that the characteristics of the "hero cult" are somehow being "inscribed" (ie, made apparent, perhaps in a subconscious way).  Or it could just be a misspelling of "description".

Comment: To tweak @HotLicks’ comment, I would read it as referring to the way the play inscribes hero cult into its cultural ‘scope’ and mythos, injecting something spectators would know from their own everyday lives into the otherwise mythological and ‘otherly’ world of the play. Kind of like when _Infinity War_ inscribes familiar ‘80s music into its fictitious and futuristic, intergalactic mythos. So it’s essentially _inscribe_ in the sense of “enrol, as on an official list” (ODO sense 4) that we’re dealing with.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet & Hot Licks - yes, this is more or less how I also understand the text; perhaps "establishing" was taking it a bit too far, trying to find a compact way to translate the sentence without creating something non-sensical in the target language. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Inscription can mean "brief dedication".

According to [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inscription), *inscription* can mean a brief dedication:

> a brief, usually informal dedication, as of a book or a work of art.

To me this connects to your quote about the Hero Cult, meaning your quote could mean: "The play's (Oedipus at Colonus) explicit dedication to hero cult is one of the ways in which the gap between the worlds of the play and the audience may be bridged."

Comment: clarification on the downvote?

Comment: This sense of _dedication_ is not the ‘devotion’ sense; it refers to when an author dedicates a book to someone (“For my husband who’s always stood by me”, etc.). That hardly seems relevant here.

Comment: Hi padfoot, I've edited to improve the formatting - you can click on the "edited ..." line to see how I did this. I've left the heading: it's not how I would do it, but there's nothing wrong with it either, it's just a matter of style.

Comment: Regarding the downvote: probably someone disagrees with your solution. I'm not sure it's right either, but I've upvoted purely because DVs are a harsh welcome to our site. Driveby DVs are something you just have to develop a thick skin for, since anonymous voting is a core and non-negotiable component of all SE sites.

Comment: @Chappo i know what downvotes are for, but thanks nonetheless! i was asking for clarification on which part of the answer the user disagreed with.

Comment: @Chappo was the markdown editing was wrong?

Comment: On this site it's strongly encouraged to include a link to the source of any quote, such as a dictionary definition. You did this (excellent!), but the formatting was unnecessarily small, and you also provided a second link to the home page of that site, which was unnecessary. Those were the two main formatting issues I fixed. And I deleted your personal message - we prefer answers to just include core content unless it's an explicit explanation of the problem (e.g. "I'm British, how to Americans say...", or "In Iran we have this proverb, is there an equivalent...").

Answer (score 0):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* has this:

> 3. spec.  a. A short piece of writing placed at the beginning of a book or other composition, descriptive of its nature, contents, authorship, etc.; a title, heading, superscription. (Now rare or Obs. as distinct from 2 [as in an engraved text].)  b. A brief dedication of a book or work of art to a person (see inscribe 2b); the superscription of a letter.

I have found no indication of a dedication or or description at the beginning of the play describing hero cult. So this sense wouldn't seem to fit.

*[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inscription)* has this:

> 4. [philosophy, linguistics]
>    an element of written language, esp a sentence
>    *Compare utterance (sense 3)*

I must admit, though, that I'm not familiar with this usage, nor do I know how common it would be. Nor yet does it seem to fit the context terribly well; but at least it seems possible.

An alternative would be some other obscure or jargon term that slipped out of its domain.

Or, lastly, it could be an error, possibly a typo erroneously corrected by the editor.